# How to modify app.component.ts property from child component in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have created different modules like login and signup. I go to login page from main page navigation link using < router-outlet>.
So menu in landing page are as below - **Menu**--
**login, Signup, Continue without login**.

When user clicks on login link, login page displayed. On success login I want to change the above menu i.e now it should be **Menu -- Your users, your orders etc.** How to achieve this in angular 2/4.

NOTE - I have created different components and modules for login and signup and only these modules(login.module.ts and signup.module.ts) are included in app.module.ts.

Comment: Use a service to hold the state of the menu. Inject this service in all components that need to get the state or update the state. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Using service I can get updated data only if I navigate to that component. In my case on login success i will navigate to home page the how can I update my menu in app.component.ts which is container of routes. Can you provide any fiiddle for your answer?

Comment: By emitting a value from an Observable in your service, and subscribing to this Observable in the app component.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand how that will work and how to implement. any resource can you provide please.

Comment: I already provided one. See the section Parent and children communicate via a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.